# Jump to next includedfile after encountering an error in included file

Tags: php, php-include

I have a main PHP file that includes lots of separate files, with no relation between them.

```
<?php
include_once 'test/test1.php';
include_once 'test/test2.php';
include_once 'test/test3.php';
include_once 'test/test4.php';
include_once 'test/test5.php';
include_once 'test/test6.php';
include_once 'test/test7.php';
?>
```

But when I run this PHP file, maybe I will encounter errors in each file.    I want to know which code is appropriate if the main file is faced with any error. It shouldn't stop working, but jump to the next file.
How can I do that?

Comment: what error are you getting??

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific? What are you trying to do, why do you expect errors?

Comment: thanks for your attention my friends, each file fetch data from different websites . sometime the server doesn't response, included files encounter error and it prevent to run other files

Comment: aren't there everyone to help me?

Answer (score 1):

`include_once` will show a warning and continue execution to the next line, it will not exit out .

`require_once` will throw the error and exit out of the program.

Comment: Additionally (although it's bad practice), you can put an `@` in from of the function to suppress any errors, e.g. `@include_once 'file.php';`.